# How to let golang distinguish XML elements with and without namespaces?

Tags: xml, go

suppose I have the following XML data:

```
<image> 
  <url> http://sampleUrl.com
  </url>
</image>

<itunes:image url="http://sampleItunesUrl.com" />  //xmlData
```

I use this struct to decode it:

```
type Response struct {
   XMLName   xml.Name   `xml:"resp"`
   Image []struct {
        URL string   `xml:"url"`
  } `xml:"image"`
  ItunesImage  struct {
       URL string `xml:"url,attr"`
  }  `xml:"http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd image"`

}
```

and I have codes like:

```
var resp Response 
err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlData), &resp)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error decoding XML: %s\n", err)
    return
}
for _, img := range resp.Image{
    if img.URL != "" {
        //<image>, not <itunes:image>
    }
}
```

to process decoding

The problem I am having is that looks like `Image []struct` considers both `<image>` and `<itunes:image` to be `<image>` element, since they both have "image". To filter out `<itunes:image`, the approach I am using is to let each one in `Image []struct` examine if their `url` are empty strings (because for `<itunes:image` its `url` is attribute).

Another approach is to write my own `Unmarshal` function to distinguish between XML elements with and without `itunes` namespace. Basically I want `Image []struct` to only hold elements `<image>`

I am wondering if go has some built-in functionalities to distinguish? Or I have to write my  codes to filter out `<itunes:image>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that the field order matters. `ItunesImage` has a more specific tag, so it should go before `Image`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type Response struct {
        XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"resp"`
        ItunesImage struct {
            URL string `xml:"url,attr"`
        } `xml:"http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd image"`
        Image []struct {
            URL string `xml:"url"`
        } `xml:"image"`
    }

    xmlData := `
<resp xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">
  <image>
    <url>http://sampleUrl.com</url>
  </image>
  <itunes:image url="http://sampleItunesUrl.com/" />
</resp>
`

    var resp Response
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlData), &resp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error decoding XML: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("ItunesImage: %v\n", resp.ItunesImage)
    fmt.Printf("Images: %v\n", resp.Image)
}
```

And if you only need `image/url` from the `<image>` tag, you could define the `Response` struct like this:

```
type Response struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"resp"`
    Image   []string `xml:"image>url"`
}
```

Regarding the general question in the title (How to let golang distinguish XML elements with and without namespaces?), you can capture the element name with a field named `XMLName` and examine the `Space` member of this field. See the demo below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type Response struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"resp"`
        Image   []struct {
            XMLName xml.Name
            URL     string `xml:"url"`
        } `xml:"image"`
    }

    xmlData := `
<resp xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">
  <image>
    <url>http://sampleUrl.com</url>
  </image>
  <itunes:image>
    <url>http://sampleItunesUrl.com/</url>
  </itunes:image>
</resp>
`

    var resp Response
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlData), &resp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error decoding XML: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    for _, img := range resp.Image {
        fmt.Printf("namespace: %q, url: %s\n", img.XMLName.Space, img.URL)
    }
}
```

The output of the above demo is:

```
namespace: "", url: http://sampleUrl.com
namespace: "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd", url: http://sampleItunesUrl.com/
```

Comment: Thank you, one thing I want to mention is that this is the question I asked chatgpt but it didn't give me satisfying answer, it suggested I could only write my own unmarshal function. You have proved that AI cannot replace humans (at least for this question)